# Session::instance() and push array data to session array

Tags: session, kohana

for example i have Session::instance()->get('orders') which is an array of some arrays:

$first = array('id' = 1, 'name' => 'first', 'price' => 100);
$second = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'second', 'price' => 200);
$_SESSION['orders'] = array($first, $second);

but if i use this

Session::instance()->set('orders', array(array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'third', 'price' => 300)));

this will erase first orders (id 1, id 2).
so how can i ADD but not ERASE data arrays to session array named 'orders'? array_push or something else?

Comment: here i coded sulution, is it good?
http://gist.github.com/502362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**, didn't see your comment, it's perfect.

Self explanatory.

```
$session = Session::instance();

// Find existing data
$data = $session->get('orders');

// Add new array
$data[] = array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'new data', 'price' => 300);

// Resave it
$session->set('orders', $data);
```

Comment: also i found that we can initialize $_SESSION array and use it as in raw php code.i mean to link Session::instance() to $_SESSIOn array because in kohana we can't manipulate with $_SESSION array directly by default.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I think that best way:

```
public function before() {
...
$this->variable = Session::instance()->get('key', array());
...
}
```

some code...

```
public function after() {
...
Session::instance()->set('key', $this->variable, Date::MINUTE);
...
}
```